# How do I implement a very basic broadcastreceiever with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an app with a feature that can auto launch if the call state changes.  Just for resting I went with a super basic implementation.  This doesn't seem to work:

```
                   val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                       override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                           Toast.makeText(context, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                       }
                   }

                   registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED))
```

I'm not getting my toast when I connect to a call.  I'm pretty new to this and the docs for broadcastreceiver has me a bit confused so I've spent a few days trying to piece together examples and advice from reddit and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the right permissions, this event (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) requires the following permission:

[Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_PHONE_STATE)